# Esconder campo obrigatório e não obrigatório

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Eu tenho um formulário. Neste formulário eu tenho dois *radiobutton* com duas opções.

```
1) Questao 1 (Obrigatorio)
1 = Sim 
2 = Nao 

______________________

2) Questao 2(Obrigatorio)
1 = Vivo
2 = Morto
```

Se esta questão 1 for = Sim a Questão 2 perde a obrigatoriedade, não irá deixar de ser uma questão obrigatória a ser respondida, mas se for = Não, a questão 2 voltará com a obrigatoriedade.

Alguém tem alguma forma em poder me ajudar com isso?

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pessoal boa tarde eu fiz a seguinte validação

```
var value = $('input[name="CAMPO1"]').val();

if (value == '1') {
    $('[name="CAMPO2"]').rules('remove', 'required');
} else {
    $('[name="CAMPO2"]').rules('add', 'required');
}
```

e funcionou perfeitamente. Agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando a validação cliente no javascript, você pode adicionar o atributo `data-val-required` e removê-lo quando não quiser que o campo seja obrigatório, algo assim:

```
// Obrigatório
$(campo).attr("data-val-required", "*");

// Não obrigatório
$(campo).removeAttr("data-val-required");
```

Pode ser necessário informar ao form para fazer o parse dos controles novamente, o que você pode fazer usando esse comando:

```
$.validator
        .unobtrusive
        .parse("form");
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso precisaria criar um *validator*, implementando `IValidatable` e `IClientValidatable`. Uma sugestão seria criar algo igual `[Required]`, mas apenas se outra propiedade ou condição fosse verdade.

Comment: Então, eu tenho um arquivo chamado validacao.js nele eu faço as validações das questões e mascaras etc
como exemplo.
$("#form-panel-AltaHospitalar").validate({
        errorClass: "input-error",
        rules: {
            dtahosp: "required",
},
Eu ja fiz diversos testes diversos metodos diferentes, só que não deu nada certo

Comment: Você está usando *unobtrusive-validation*? Ou simplesmente *jquery-validate*?

Comment: somente o  jquery-validate